# Detect Keyboard present in VB6

Tags: keyboard, vb6

I have a legacy VB6 project that can now run on systems without a keybord attached. In that case the program opens the MS on screen keyboard. I need to detect if a keyboard is attached or not. If there is a keyboard attached then skip opening the the on screen keyboard. At the moment it opens the on screen keyboard and the user must then close it. It is Clunky. I cannot migrate this application because it supports some legacy equipment that cannot be accessed by VB.net. Any Ideas please.

Answer (score 4):

[Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/windows-remote-management-and-wmi) is one way you could go.  The following code looks for keyboards with an OK status:

```
Private Function hasKeyboard() As Boolean
   Dim WMIService As Object
   Dim Items As Object
   Dim Item As Object

   hasKeyboard = False
   Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
   Set Items = WMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard")

   For Each Item In Items
      If InStr(1, UCase(Item.Status), "OK") > 0 Then
         hasKeyboard = True
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: Wow - there's a lot of rummaging around in documentation buried in that one line!  I tried this succinct little function, and it works great (although I have no idea how) - it's now part of my library of useful things.  Thanks!